# Xcode can't reference images inside subfolder in c++

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a folder in my root project folder, i inserted images and assets but i can't reference them.
The subfolder is called resources, it is yellow, and when i inserted the files i selected copy if necessary.
then i have this in my code `texture.loadFromFile("resources/paddle.png")` but it can't be found.
How do i make these resources available?
The instructions i found point at a menu that i don't even have.
this is the folder:
[image]

EDIT: my application is a c++ application.

Comment: A relative path is resolved relative to the application's current working directory, not relative to a project folder or the directory (or bundle) that contains the executable. You're probably going to want to use [`NSBundle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle).

Comment: it doesn't look like there is a version in c++, looks like a swift object

Comment: `NSBundle` is an Objective-C class. You're going to need to learn some Objective-C if you want to make "proper" Mac applications.